# C# pass textbox value to datetimepicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio

in my textbox i have the value of "07-31-2017". I want this value to be passed on my datetimepicker1. so datetimepicker1 could display the value of my textbox.

in vb.net the code goes like this:

`dateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Parse(textbox.Text)`

but how in C#?

Comment: You need to improve your research skills.

Answer (score 2):

```
dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox.Text);
```

Only works if there is a valid datetime value in the textbox. Unless you are 100% sure the format is right, i'd not recommend to use a textbox.

There is also a TryParse() option to make sure the datetime is right.

```
        DateTime newDateTime;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out newDateTime))
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Value = newDateTime;
        }
        else
        {
            // Datetime is invalid
        }
```

Comment: What's the point of using `.Parse()` a second time when you already have the value in `out newDateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

building on @Michael Tralala's answer:

```
    DateTime newDateTime;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out newDateTime))
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = newDateTime;
    }
    else
    {
        // Datetime is invalid
    }
```

The DateTime.TryParse will return a `boolean` depending on if the string can be converted to a DateTime.  We can use the `out newDateTime` to reduce the amount of code and conversions, and we are basically guaranteed that the value of the textbox will not change between evaluations.  An example of where it might change would be a multi-threaded app.

Also, we can use the `ELSE` of the `IF` to handle unexpected conversion problems.  This is a lot better than using just `DateTime.Parse`, since `DateTime.Parse` could throw an exception, which could be very expensive to generate, depending on where this code would be used.

Answer (score -1):

Simple

```
    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dateTimePicker1.Value =DateTime.Parse( label.Text);
    }
```

.....

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It would be really nice if you could give some explanation to your code